# What is this non-printing character in a word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document (v16.57) that in some places has a new line with a paragraph marker (after "Protection"), and in others a dot (for instance after "Station" or "USA").

[image]

It doesn't appear to be a space, as when I search for a space, they are highlighted between words, but those dots at the end are not.  It's also not a line return ('^l'). And it is not possible to highlight in word.

I'm trying to parse this document in R, but it doesn't recognize any special character there regardless of how I read it in; instead it mushes all those lines into a single line with no delimiter.

If I copy paste the document to a plain text editor, there are no line breaks where the dot character is:

[image]

And the same thing happens if I paste it into excel, regardless of using various types of 'paste special'.

[image]

UPDATE:

It appears that those lines are breaking because of the margin indent settings.  If I set both the left and right margin indents to 0, those lines no longer have breaks in the same location:

[image]

Looking at a text file pasted from the word file, the hex value for those are `20`, which is a space (I think?).

What's still puzzling me is why the margins were causing the breaks to be where they should be in terms of separating street address from town, zip, country.  I would think that it would just be after a certain number of characters that was wider than the margins (which it is when the line is very long) but it always breaks at the correct place to separate address lines.

Regardless, is there any way to parse the word doc text with line returns where they are visible in the word document and those dots?

Answer (score 2):

Character value `0x0a` is a line-feed. This is the end-of-line character
on Linux, but on Windows an additional carriage-return is required to
make it into a real end-of-line.

Some text-editors on Windows will show it as
an end-of-line, while others won't.

I have no idea why would anyone sprinkle a text document with line-feeds.
Perhaps you should post online some example.

Comment: Sorry I gave bad info.  The hex value at the end of the lines with the dots is `20`.  The places where there is a `0a` are the paragraph returns.

Comment: This is then a simple blank, replaced by a dot for readability. It has no other meaning.